# Pass parameters to SQL in Databricks (Python)

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have this field from a dataframe that I need to use as parameter for a SQl, so I'm using the code below and it throws  empty, no error, just nothing.

```
d = df_max_dt.select('update_tstmp');
df_tmp = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE last_upd_tstmp > from_utc_timestamp('{0}', 'MST') ".format(d);
```

However, if I manually replace the parameter like this below, it does work:

```
df_tmp = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE last_upd_tstmp > from_utc_timestamp('{0}', 'MST') ".format('2020-02-25T18:54:48.435+0000'))
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check printing the "d" variable before assigning it to see if it has a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `d` is a dataframe. Try this:

```
d = df_max_dt.select('update_tstmp').collect()[0].update_tstmp;
df_tmp = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE last_upd_tstmp > from_utc_timestamp('{0}', 'MST') ".format(d);
```